# Sort a list of files based on numeric value in name

Tags: bash, sorting

I have this list of files and I want to sort them and increment their names by an integer value, my code works fine until the list hits 10. The linux 'sort' command then interprets the first '1' in '10' and thinks it is a smaller number than 9. Is there any way to make this work ?

This is the code I have written to loop over a folder and increment file names:

```
#!/bin/bash

#set -x
ROOT=~/testing/
FILE_COUNT=$(ls -1 $ROOT | wc -l | awk '{print $1}')
COUNT=5

if [[ ${FILE_COUNT} -eq $COUNT ]]; then
    echo $COUNT backup files are there

    FILE_LIST=$(ls -1 $ROOT | sort -n -r)

    for file in $FILE_LIST; do
        echo $file
        file_new=`basename $file .zip`
        if [[ -e $ROOT$file ]]; then
            #mv $ROOT$file $ROOT${file_new%?}$COUNT.zip
            FILENUM=${file_new:${#file_new}-1}
            #echo "This is file # $FILENUM" next one is $(( FILENUM + 1 ))
            echo mv $ROOT$file $ROOT${file_new%?}$(( FILENUM + 1 )).zip
            mv $ROOT$file $ROOT${file_new%?}$(( FILENUM + 1 )).zip
        fi
        ((COUNT--))
    done
else
    echo Not $COUNT files, there are $FILE_COUNT
    COUNT=$FILE_COUNT
fi
```

And these are the results of the sort line:

```
macbookair:~ ilium007$ ls -l testing/ | sort -n -r -t "_"
total 40
-rw-r--r--  1 ilium007  staff  15 16 Nov 21:24 backup_9.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 ilium007  staff  15 16 Nov 21:24 backup_8.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 ilium007  staff  15 16 Nov 21:24 backup_7.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 ilium007  staff  15 16 Nov 21:24 backup_6.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 ilium007  staff  15 16 Nov 21:24 backup_10.zip
```

How do I create this list of files:

```
backup_10.zip
backup_9.zip
backup_8.zip
backup_7.zip
backup_6.zip
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the key to sort on, in this case `-k2`:

```
ls | sort -n -r -t "_" -k2
```

Comment: That worked beautifully until I got to 20 !
backup_19.zip
mv /Users/ilium007/testing/backup_19.zip /Users/ilium007/testing/backup_110.zip`
My code is:    
`FILE_LIST=$(ls -1 $ROOT | sort -n -r -t "_" -k2)`

Comment: That has got nothing to do with the sorting. You're not incrementing the files correctly. That's why backup_19 becomes backup_110. This is the problem `FILENUM=${file_new:${#file_new}-1}`.

Comment: use this instead: `FILENUM=${file_new##*_}`

Comment: I am almost there now ! I have this line that is now causing issues:

    `echo mv $ROOT$file $ROOT${file_new%?}$(( FILENUM + 1 )).zip`

It only strips off one character so when I go from 19 to 20 I still get 120.

Comment: Change `${file_new%?}` to `${file_new%%_*}`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19638/discussion-between-ilium007-and-dogbane)

Answer (score 0):

This code ended up working:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
ROOT=~/testing/
FILE_COUNT=$(ls -1 $ROOT | wc -l | awk '{print $1}')
COUNT=5
FILENAME=("backup_19.zip"
"backup_2.zip
"backup_29.zip
"backup_38.zip")
for i in ${FILENAME[@]}; do
BASE_FILE_NAME=`basename $i .zip`
FILENUM=${BASE_FILE_NAME##*_}
NEW_FILE_NUM=$(( FILENUM + 1 ))
NEW_FILE_SUFFIX=$(( FILENUM + 1 )).zip
TEST=${BASE_FILE_NAME%%_*}_${NEW_FILE_SUFFIX}
done
exit
```